# Unauthorized access in reverse ssh tunnel

Tags: ssh, port-forwarding, ssh-tunnel

I created a reverse ssh tunnel between an internal work website and my home workstation. My aim was to work on the remote internal website from my workstation.
There is only a computer between the ends and the issue comes from it. On that computer, there is a ssh client that initiates the tunnel. There is also a ssh server running on that computer but for other needs.
I used this syntaxe below to build the reverse tunnel:

`ssh -R 9001:internal-website.com:443 root@homeworkstation.com`

Everything worked fine.  But when I checked the connections on the computer between the two ends, I noticed an unauthorized access, and the IP address is from China (121.18.238.125):

```
root@windy:~# lsof -i
COMMAND   PID USER   FD   TYPE DEVICE SIZE/OFF NODE NAME
dhclient 3356 root    6u  IPv4   5492      0t0  UDP *:bootpc 
ntpd     3459  ntp   16u  IPv6   8537      0t0  UDP *:ntp 
ntpd     3459  ntp   17u  IPv4   8540      0t0  UDP *:ntp 
ntpd     3459  ntp   18u  IPv4   8544      0t0  UDP localhost:ntp 
ntpd     3459  ntp   19u  IPv4   8546      0t0  UDP 10.4.103.17:ntp 
ntpd     3459  ntp   20u  IPv6   8548      0t0  UDP localhost:ntp 
ntpd     3459  ntp   21u  IPv6   8550      0t0  UDP [fe80::dc19:68ff:fe13:d008]:ntp 
sshd     3463 root    3u  IPv4   8572      0t0  TCP 10.4.103.17:ssh->home-server:47730 (ESTABLISHED)
sshd     3663 root    3u  IPv4   8736      0t0  TCP *:ssh (LISTEN)
sshd     3663 root    4u  IPv6   8738      0t0  TCP *:ssh (LISTEN)
sshd     3878 root    3u  IPv4   8992      0t0  TCP 10.4.103.17:ssh->home-server:48680 (ESTABLISHED)
sshd     4092 root    3u  IPv4  10068      0t0  TCP 10.4.103.17:ssh->home-server:48092 (ESTABLISHED)
ssh      4445 root    3u  IPv4  14454      0t0  TCP 10.4.103.17:60988->home-server:ssh (ESTABLISHED)
sshd     4481 root    3u  IPv4  15428      0t0  TCP 10.4.103.17:ssh->121.18.238.125:53763 (ESTABLISHED)
sshd     4482 sshd    3u  IPv4  15428      0t0  TCP 10.4.103.17:ssh->121.18.238.125:53763 (ESTABLISHED)
```

In the /var/log/auth.log file, I couldn't find anything suspicious. Only normal ssh failed attempts. I even found the same address among the failed attempts. I did that experience twice. The first time I deactivated the root password login and set the public key connection. and the second time, I set the password login with a strong password for the root user. And both experiences gave me the same result (different addresses each time but still from china).
How could possibly this computer between the two ends got compromised ? Am I missing something ? I can't figure out where the weak spot is.

For the home workstation to be available to the internet, I enabled a port forwarding on the local router. Once again, I used a strong password and I didn't find any suspicious connection on it.

If you didn't get me well, please don't hesitate to ask for further information.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like your lsof -i ist just seeing one of these failed login attempts.

To see similar output you might try to ssh to windy like

```
ssh windy -l non-existend-user
```

and watch lsof output while your login attempt asks for a password.

TomTomTom